# Custom Laravel Directory Install With Composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I was wondering if it was possible to create a custom laravel "template" with composer.

For example, I want to include in my composer's create-project laravel/laravel install these two extensions by default,
https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon
https://github.com/maxhoffmann/parsedown-laravel

or additional folders in the root directory so I don't have to re-create them each time.

I don't mean to ask how to install those ^ above,

but I mean to ask how to set it up so that 
when i run 
composer create-project laravel/laravel projName 
It automatically has those files/extensions/etc
created and/or installed

Comment: It will does everything for you automatically, you need to add the `package` in `composer.json` file.

Comment: But isn't that After the project is already created?
I'm looking for it to have an install WITH whatever modifications,
otherwise, what is the source that composer creates from? Is that what you mean to modify?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the project dependencies/packages in `composer` and then run `composer update`, that's it.

Comment: Right, but i mean to ask, is there a way to have it so I don't need to keep re-adding these dependencies/packages. 
As in, with every time I run a new composer project install, they're included automatically.. I feel like we're on different pages

Comment: Oh! no. you can't do that that, every project requires a different `composer.json` file :-)

Comment: Haha, there we go :P 

alright i'll keep poking around, hopefully eventually i'll find a better way

Answer (score 1):

Just add `maxhoffmann/parsedown-laravel` in your `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*", // version could be 4.2.*
    "maxhoffmann/parsedown-laravel": "dev-master"
},
```

The `Carbon` package is already avaiable with `Laravel` by default. Also in `app/config/app.php` add another entry in `providers` array like this ([Check details here](https://github.com/maxhoffmann/parsedown-laravel)):

```
'providers' => array(
    // other entries...
    'MaxHoffmann\Parsedown\ParsedownServiceProvider'
),
```

Also add an entry in `aliases` array like this:

```
'aliases' => array(
    // other entries...
    'Markdown'        => 'MaxHoffmann\Parsedown\ParsedownFacade',
),
```

You said:

> or additional folders in the root directory so I don't have to
>   re-create them each time.

It doesn't make any sense, sorry!.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can load custom libraries and have them autoloaded via composers "autoload" section. How you actually load the code into you project is up to you. git submodules is a good option. I'm not familiar with the Laravel directory structure so replace the paths to something that fits:

```
{
    "require": {
        // requires go here
    },
    "require-dev": {
        // require dev go here
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0" : {
            "Carbon": "src/lib/Carbon/src",
            "Carbon\\Test": "src/lib/Carbon/tests"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably best thing to do is install default Laravel, configure as you wish then save your default template on github... that way you can just do `git clone url_to_your_template_repository`?